# Put a fragment in a specific container when you have several copies

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a pager adapter with 4 copies of the same fragment. Each of them has the same fragment container that has to be filled with another fragment when a specific view is clicked in its fragment. I do that with

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.gear_change_container,fragment).commit();
```

but that always put the fragment in the container of the fragment in the first tab.

How can I refer specifically to the container within the tab the click is made?

Comment: Use `getChildFragmentManager()` inside the `Fragment` class, instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: I get this error: declared target fragment does not belong to this fragment manager.
In the pageradapter I use getSupportFragmentManager and it won't let me use getChildFragmentManager.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you're trying to handle this, but any `Fragment`s inside other `Fragment`s need to be handled by the appropriate child `FragmentManager`, inside the parent `Fragment`s themselves. If you're manually setting the parent `Fragment` as the target `Fragment` on those nested `Fragment`s, then you just can't do that anymore. You'll need to use some other method to communicate between them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I converted all my comunication between fragments to childFragmentManager and it works properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how I would replace a fragment inside a fragment using Kotlin extension.

```
fun Fragment.replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment?, frameId: Int, addToBackStack: Boolean = true) {
fragment?.let {
    childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .apply {
                if (addToBackStack) addToBackStack(null)
            }
            .replace(frameId, fragment)
            .commit()
   }
}
```

Hope this will help.